# Scrolling Delegate in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to make an animation like this link:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/420523683937443901/sent/?sender=335307272165049646&invite_code=f63f81c77d28a48e6181db7df90b423a

Here is my simple screenshot:

[image]

In my case, I want when I swiping up, the blue Header View will disappear and the navigation bar will change to blue color.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var headerView: UIView!

    var dataSource: [String] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14].map {"\($0)"}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

I can change the views with animation like this, include: Navigation Bar, Header View of TableView, Status Bar.

But how to check when the TableView scroll down, then the Header View will change.

Comment: Have you have just write some code about your tableView?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just want to ask how to check this event (When the tableView is scrolling down or scrolling up)

Comment: So put some code here, some pictures to clear understand your question and your project to do..dont rely on http links, they can be unavailable and your question will doesnt make sense

Comment: Good change, now it's clear 1+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your tableView to intercept scrollView actions with:

```
class YourClass: YourType, UIScrollViewDelegate {}
```

Check the [official apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/)

You can handle scrollview looking for [scrollViewDidScroll(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) method.

This is just an example to add more network data when the user scroll to the end, you can use it to trigger your header animation..

```
let threshold = 100.0 // threshold from bottom of tableView
var isLoadingMore = false // flag

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    if !isLoadingMore && (maximumOffset - contentOffset <= threshold) {
        // Get more data - API call
        self.isLoadingMore = true

        // Update UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            tableView.reloadData()
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

By analizying your animation, it's not simple but not impossible :) 
I can see two different states:

[image]

And the second state:

[image]

You can organize your controller by choose a `UIViewController` type.
This UIViewController must be composed by:

- -**UINavigationController** (as you can see on the top of the images , choose if you want to embedded it or link a navigation controller and set your viewController as the navigation
  rootViewController)
- -**UIPageView** (you can use in your main viewController with the UIPageViewControllerDataSource and UIPageViewControllerDelegate, pay attention to the dimension , it cover the 30% of the top of your controller)
- -**UITableView** (this is the last layout part, everytime page scroller the datasource can be changed and refreshed to the table)

P.S. The tableViewHeader can be the gray label with the date: Thursday 21 January 2016, as you can see the dimension dont change during animation.

Comment: But we are using TableView, not Scroll View, is it possible?

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, sure it's possible.

Comment: When I add your code, the navigation bar color change when I swiping up (scrolling down).Thanks. I will try to make it more similar to that link.

Comment: It is now available in https://github.com/khuong291/Swift_Example_Series (Project 53).

Comment: Wow,it's very similar to the original photo here, I've see MovingUpHeaderView.gif, good joob.

Comment: Thank you. I will try more.