# UIViewController Animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout, ios-animations

I am new here and trying to build an iOS app and it has some designs related to UIViewController animation during scrolling and button tapping etc.

Please take a look at the below diagram for more info. It would be very nice if someone can direct me to the correct way about how should I achieve it.
[image]

Comment: Flagged to close because we're not here to make the work for you.

Comment: Yeah! I know that no one will work for me but I need some rough idea about how to achieve that thing thats all. @David'mArm'Ansermot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago I was speaking with a [Khuong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4742830/khuong) who ask information to a similar project, about the analysys and the required elements , you can find the stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37000238/1894067) .

After, he have realized also a project you can find [here - github repo](https://github.com/khuong291/100DaysOfSwift) under the name "MovingUpHeaderView". Hope you help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Let me do some research on that and I will let you know if anything happens. By the way the links are just very helpful I think.

Comment: What about your project , is it the same ?

Comment: That was very helpful. Not same but got an idea about how to achieve that and almost solved the question which I asked for. Thanks to you.

Comment: Finally giving you +1 vote because the idea worked for me and helped me to learn a lot and new things too.

Comment: Nice to know it, good luck