# make pan gesture recognizer only respond when swiping down AND at the top of a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to dismiss the current viewcontroller when the user swipes down at the top of the tableView. Since the tableview takes up the whole screen, my gesture and the `tableView`'s gesture conflicts.

I thought about making my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` only respond if the user has not scrolled the tableview (`tableView.contentOffset.y == 0.0`) and the direction of the swipe is downwards. However, I have not succeeded implementing this.

This is my code:

```
var tableGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
var oPosition: CGPoint?
var currentPosition: CGPoint?
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self

    tableGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableGesture(_:)))
    table.addGestureRecognizer(tableGesture!)
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let translation = tableGesture?.translation(in: table)
    return translation!.y > 0 && table.contentOffset.y == 0.0
}
```

I have looked around at similar questions but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: Why downvote? Would appreciate explanation in case I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is add another clear view on top of your tableView and add a pan gesture recognizer to this view.  It can be quite short (I tried 20 points and that works fine).  You can override scrollViewDidScroll and set isHidden to true only when contentOffset.y <= 0.  The invisible view will now detect pans that start int he top 20 points of the tableview only when you are at the top of the tableView.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very critical to handle single action `Top` or `Bottom` swipe, where two gestures are enabled and detects same events.

A simple logical solution I can suggest

Detect scroll position of tableview and if table row index is zero or content offset for table scroll is zero: Identify swipe down event and close/dismiss your view controller.

Here is similar kind of solution, that you can use:
- [Scrolling Delegate in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000238/scrolling-delegate-in-tableview/37000621#37000621)

Comment: So you suggest using the `tableView`'s own gesture handler?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, this is what you need.

Considering your tableview is a scrollview, this function will run whenever the user scrolls on your table and you can get the coordinates of the scroll by calling table.contentOffset.y .

```
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    print("the user scrolled down",table.contentOffset.y)


    if (self.lastContentOffset > tableView.contentOffset.y) {
        //scrolling up

    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < tableView.contentOffset.y) {
        // scrolling down

        // dismiss your view here.

    }


    if table.contentOffset.y < 5 {

        // the following code will be called when the user scrolls back up

        // show the view again if thats what you need


    }


    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it this way but the result was somewhat buggy unfortunately.